# Why I am not able to connect to Informix14.10 installed on RedHat 8 Linux, using ODBC 64 bit for Windows 10?

Tags: odbc, redhat, informix

I have installed Informix 14.10 on Redhat 8 Linux.
The IP Address of the server is `192.168.183.129`
I am able to ping it from Windows successfully
The hostname is `localhost.localdomain`
The DBSERVERNAME `ol_informix1410`
The $INFORMIXDIR/etc/sqlhosts is as follows:

```
#dbserver   net_Type Host_Name  Service_Name
ol_informix1410 onsoctcp localhost.localdomain ol_informix1410 
dr_informix1410 drsoctcp localhost.localdomain dr_informix1410 
lo_informix1410 onsoctcp 127.0.0.1 lo_informix1410 
ol_informix1410 onsoctcp 192.168.183.129  ol_informix1410
```

The /etc/hosts contains:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
192.168.183.129   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
```

The services on linux have the following ports:

```
ol_informix1410         10070/tcp                                               
ol_informix1410_json    27017/tcp
```

when running the dbaccess on Linux

```
DBACCESS:   Query-language  Connection  Database  Table  Session  Exit
Retrieve information about the current DB-Access session.

----------- superstore_demo@ol_informix1410 ------ Press CTRL-W for Help ------

Server
   ol_informix1410
   Dynamic Server
   Connected to host192.168.183.129
   Multi-threaded

Server Capabilities
   NLS
   Distributed
   XA

NLS Capabilities and Attributes
   en_US.819 Collating Sequence
   en_US.819 CType
```

I Installed the IBM INFORMIX ODBC DRIVER (64-bit), version 4.50.00.18347 (file:ICLIT09B.DLL) date 23/10/2021 on Microsoft windows 10.

Then added a new system DSN as follows:
[ODBC DSN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENWNW.png)

When I press Apply & Test Connection button, I get the following error: `**Test connection was not successful. [Informix][Informix ODBC Driver][Informix] System error occurred in network function.**`

Any suggestion?

Comment: Why do you have two "ol_informix1410" on the server sqlhosts?
Try having just one, and maybe, replace the host_name value with a * so the server will spawn a listener thread for all your network interfaces.

Comment: @jsagrera: In the sqlhosts, I kept only one "ol_informix1410" without success.

Then I tried to changed the hostname to INF and modified both the sqlhosts and /etc/hosts files without success too Thank you for the suggestion

Comment: @JeroniChamorro: In the setnet32, I edited the INFORMIXSERVER environment variable to "ol_informix1410" and retried without success too, thank you for the suggestion

Comment: You don't really need to register the server in setnet32 (registry) as you can specify all the required parameters (host/port/server) in the connection string.
Just for testing purposes, try changing the 3rd column in the server sqlhosts and use a "*", so you should be able to connect from all the network interfaces (127, 192, etc).
On the windows side, i suggest to first try a dbaccess connection. You will need to create %INFORMIXDIR\etc\sqlhosts file with the same content as the server. (use 10070 as the port so you don't need to touch the Windows services file).

Comment: If you can get Windows dbaccess to connect, ODBC should work too (assuming DSN/setnet32 details are the same)

Comment: @jsagrera, you're right, I've tested it now and it's not necessary, many years ago it only worked for me after configuring setnet32 correctly and I assumed it was necessary.

Comment: @jsagrera, thank you for your suggestions, and followup.
It turn out that the firewall is running on Redhat8. I stopped it and tried again. ODBC connected successfully.
I think I should now open the port 10070 on the firewall and then start the firewall. Right?

Comment: CSDK on Windows works in mysterious ways ;) . Some APIs take values from the registry, others from the registry or env. What I always do when dealing with connection errors is reducing layers like with an onion. My first tests is always old telnet to host/port. That should give you an error on the server side, but it will tell you that the client can reach the server. From there on, I move to basic connectivity (like esql/dbaccess) and then whatever driver I want to test (ODBC/NET/OLEDB).
Definitely need to allow traffic through the Informix port, Informix is good, but not that good.

Comment: Yes: if the Linux box blocks connections on port 10070, you won't be able to connect from another machine.  You must open the port(s) you wish to connect to on the RedHat machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, I had to open the port 10070/tcp in the Redhat firewall. After restarting the firewall, ODBC connected successfully.

Thank you `@jsagrera` and `@JeroniChamorro` for your suggestions.